# Access python interpreter in VSCode version controll when using pre-commit

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I'm using pre-commit for most of my Python projects, and in many of them, I need to use pylint as a local repo. When I want to commit, I always have to activate python venv and then commit; otherwise, I'll get the following error:

```bash
black....................................................................Passed
pylint...................................................................Failed
- hook id: pylint
- exit code: 1

Executable `pylint` not found
```

When I use vscode version control to commit, I get the same error; I searched about the problem and didn't find any solution to avoid the error in VSCode.

This is my typical `.pre-commit-config.yaml`:

```yaml
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/ambv/black
    rev: 21.9b0
    hooks:
    - id: black
      language_version: python3.8
      exclude: admin_web/urls\.py
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    -   id: pylint
        name: pylint
        entry: pylint
        language: python
        types: [python]
        args: 
         - --rcfile=.pylintrc
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have ~essentially two options here -- neither are great (`language: system` is kinda the unsupported escape hatch so it's on you to make those things available on `PATH`)

you could use a specific path to the virtualenv `entry: venv/bin/pylint` -- though that will reduce the portability.

or you could start vscode with your virtualenv activated (usually `code .`) -- this doesn't always work if vscode is already running

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit

Comment: Thank you @anthony-sottile, for your great framework and your answer. Do you think it is possible to fix this problem by creating an extension to extend vscode source control and run commands inside virtual environments? And is the problem exists in Pycharm too? If there is a way to add (kind of) native support to vscode, I will be happy to work on it.

Comment: Hey Anthony, I found another solution that makes your suggestion portable! I would like to have your opinion about that solution.

Comment: poetry is not portable -- I definitely don't have it globally available on my computer and neither will all of your contributors

Comment: Ok, So I Accept your answer again, but in my opinion, it is a little more portable than `venv/bin/pylint`.

Comment: Can't imagine why `entry` does't work with `pylint` even if it parsed. But yeah, `entry: venv/bin/pylint` works.

Answer (score 1):

I found a great solution. Use poetry!

When you are using `poetry`, you can easily access your environment by using `poetry run command`. That's the trick to accessing local `pylint`.

Here is an example using `poetry`; everything is the same except language and entry:

```yaml
repos:
    - repo: https://github.com/ambv/black
      rev: 21.9b0
      hooks:
          - id: black
            language_version: python3.8
            exclude: admin_web/urls\.py
    - repo: local
      hooks:
          - id: pylint
            name: pylint
            entry: poetry run pylint # was pylint before
            language: system # was python before
            types: [python]
            args:
                - --rcfile=.pylintrc
```

And works like a charm in VScode!

Comment: I also decided to go for this solution; only difference is I'm using hatch https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/ instead of poetry

Answer (score 0):

As @Mehdi i used pdm instead of poetry and did the work !!
Make sure to not push .pdm-python that it contains the path of the venv python interpreter to your repo

If there is any updates about configuring vscode source control to point to the venv python interpreter instead of the python system without using package management tools i'll take !!!